# Is there a way for my discord bot to change a message it sent prior, completing replacing that message with a new one?

Tags: python, button, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a connect 4 game in discord.py, using buttons to place pieces. Currently, it resends a new gameboard every time a piece is placed, with the buttons causing issues as they display "this interaction failed", even though its code ran fine.

So is there a way to edit the message of the game board to prevent this issue?

```
def place(name, Line, row):
  open_file = open(name, "r")
  board = []
  piece = open_file.readline().strip("\n")
  for x in range(6):
    value = open_file.readline()
    board.append(value.strip("\n").split(","))
  open_file.close()
  Place = True
  while Place and Line != 6:
    if board[Line][row - 1] == ":white_large_square:":
      Line += 1
    else:
      Place = False
  if not board[0][row - 1] == piece:
    Line -= 1
    board[Line][row - 1] = piece
    Line1 = ",".join(board[0])
    Line2 = ",".join(board[1])
    Line3 = ",".join(board[2])
    Line4 = ",".join(board[3])
    Line5 = ",".join(board[4])
    Line6 = ",".join(board[5])
    Lines = [Line1, Line2, Line3, Line4, Line5, Line6]
    phrase = "\n".join(Lines)
    new_piece = ""
    if piece == ":green_circle:":
      new_piece = ":red_circle:\n"
    elif piece == ":red_circle:":
      new_piece = ":green_circle:\n"
    open_file = open(name, "w")
    open_file.write(new_piece + phrase)
    open_file.close()
    return "Valid Move"
  else:
    return "Invalid Move"


@bot.command(
  brief=" Begins your Connect 4 Game",
  description=
  " Displays the board and buttons, which will place your piece in the desired lane",
  Arguments="None")
async def Connect4(ctx):
  open_file = open(ctx.author.name + "#", "w")
  open_file.write(
    ":green_circle:\n:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:\n:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:\n:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:\n:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:\n:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:\n:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:,:white_large_square:"
  )
  open_file.close()
  open_file = open(ctx.author.name + "#", "r")
  board = []
  piece = open_file.readline()
  for _ in range(6):
    value = open_file.readline()
    board.append(value.strip("\n").split(","))
  open_file.close()
  L1 = "".join(board[0])
  L2 = "".join(board[1])
  L3 = "".join(board[2])
  L4 = "".join(board[3])
  L5 = "".join(board[4])
  L6 = "".join(board[5])

  button1 = Button(label="",
                   emoji="1️⃣",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray,
                   row=0)
  button2 = Button(label="",
                   emoji="2️⃣",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray,
                   row=0)
  button3 = Button(label="",
                   emoji="3️⃣",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray,
                   row=0)
  button4 = Button(label="",
                   emoji="4️⃣",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray,
                   row=1)
  button5 = Button(label="",
                   emoji="5️⃣",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray,
                   row=1)
  button6 = Button(label="",
                   emoji="6️⃣",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray,
                   row=1)
  button7 = Button(label="",
                   emoji="7️⃣",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray,
                   row=1)

  async def button1Clicked(interaction):

    x = place(ctx.author.name + "#", 0, 1)
    if x == "Invalid Move":
      await ctx.send("Invalid Move")
    else:
      open_file = open(ctx.author.name + "#", "r")
      board = []
      piece = open_file.readline()
      for _ in range(6):
        value = open_file.readline()
        board.append(value.strip("\n").split(","))
      open_file.close()
      L1 = "".join(board[0])
      L2 = "".join(board[1])
      L3 = "".join(board[2])
      L4 = "".join(board[3])
      L5 = "".join(board[4])
      L6 = "".join(board[5])
      message = piece + " turn\n" +L1 + "\n" + L2 + "\n" + L3 + "\n" + L4 + "\n" + L5 + "\n" + L6
      await ctx.send(message, view=view1)

  async def button2Clicked(interaction):

    x = place(ctx.author.name + "#", 0, 2)
    if x == "Invalid Move":
      await ctx.send("Invalid Move")
    else:
      open_file = open(ctx.author.name + "#", "r")
      board = []
      piece = open_file.readline()
      for _ in range(6):
        value = open_file.readline()
        board.append(value.strip("\n").split(","))
      open_file.close()
      L1 = "".join(board[0])
      L2 = "".join(board[1])
      L3 = "".join(board[2])
      L4 = "".join(board[3])
      L5 = "".join(board[4])
      L6 = "".join(board[5])
      message = piece + " turn\n" +L1 + "\n" + L2 + "\n" + L3 + "\n" + L4 + "\n" + L5 + "\n" + L6
      await ctx.send(message, view=view1)


  async def button3Clicked(interaction):
    x = place(ctx.author.name + "#", 0, 3)
    if x == "Invalid Move":
      await ctx.send("Invalid Move")
    else:
      open_file = open(ctx.author.name + "#", "r")
      board = []
      piece = open_file.readline()
      for _ in range(6):
        value = open_file.readline()
        board.append(value.strip("\n").split(","))
      open_file.close()
      L1 = "".join(board[0])
      L2 = "".join(board[1])
      L3 = "".join(board[2])
      L4 = "".join(board[3])
      L5 = "".join(board[4])
      L6 = "".join(board[5])
      message = piece + " turn\n" +L1 + "\n" + L2 + "\n" + L3 + "\n" + L4 + "\n" + L5 + "\n" + L6
      await ctx.send(message, view=view1)

  async def button4Clicked(interaction):
    x = place(ctx.author.name + "#", 0, 4)
    if x == "Invalid Move":
      await ctx.send("Invalid Move")
    else:
      open_file = open(ctx.author.name + "#", "r")
      board = []
      piece = open_file.readline()
      for _ in range(6):
        value = open_file.readline()
        board.append(value.strip("\n").split(","))
      open_file.close()
      L1 = "".join(board[0])
      L2 = "".join(board[1])
      L3 = "".join(board[2])
      L4 = "".join(board[3])
      L5 = "".join(board[4])
      L6 = "".join(board[5])
      message = piece + " turn\n" +L1 + "\n" + L2 + "\n" + L3 + "\n" + L4 + "\n" + L5 + "\n" + L6
      await ctx.send(message, view=view1)

  async def button5Clicked(interaction):
    x = place(ctx.author.name + "#", 0, 5)
    if x == "Invalid Move":
      await ctx.send("Invalid Move")
    else:
      open_file = open(ctx.author.name + "#", "r")
      board = []
      piece = open_file.readline()
      for _ in range(6):
        value = open_file.readline()
        board.append(value.strip("\n").split(","))
      open_file.close()
      L1 = "".join(board[0])
      L2 = "".join(board[1])
      L3 = "".join(board[2])
      L4 = "".join(board[3])
      L5 = "".join(board[4])
      L6 = "".join(board[5])
      message = piece + " turn\n" +L1 + "\n" + L2 + "\n" + L3 + "\n" + L4 + "\n" + L5 + "\n" + L6
      await ctx.send(message, view=view1)
      
  async def button6Clicked(interaction):
    x = place(ctx.author.name + "#", 0, 6)
    if x == "Invalid Move":
      await ctx.send("Invalid Move")
    else:
      open_file = open(ctx.author.name + "#", "r")
      board = []
      piece = open_file.readline()
      for _ in range(6):
        value = open_file.readline()
        board.append(value.strip("\n").split(","))
      open_file.close()
      L1 = "".join(board[0])
      L2 = "".join(board[1])
      L3 = "".join(board[2])
      L4 = "".join(board[3])
      L5 = "".join(board[4])
      L6 = "".join(board[5])
      message = piece + " turn\n" +L1 + "\n" + L2 + "\n" + L3 + "\n" + L4 + "\n" + L5 + "\n" + L6
      await ctx.send(message, view=view1)

  async def button7Clicked(interaction):
    x = place(ctx.author.name + "#", 0, 7)
    if x == "Invalid Move":
      await ctx.send("Invalid Move")
    else:
      open_file = open(ctx.author.name + "#", "r")
      board = []
      piece = open_file.readline()
      for _ in range(6):
        value = open_file.readline()
        board.append(value.strip("\n").split(","))
      open_file.close()
      L1 = "".join(board[0])
      L2 = "".join(board[1])
      L3 = "".join(board[2])
      L4 = "".join(board[3])
      L5 = "".join(board[4])
      L6 = "".join(board[5])
      message = piece + " turn\n" +L1 + "\n" + L2 + "\n" + L3 + "\n" + L4 + "\n" + L5 + "\n" + L6
      await ctx.send(message, view=view1)
      
  button1.callback = button1Clicked
  button2.callback = button2Clicked
  button3.callback = button3Clicked
  button4.callback = button4Clicked
  button5.callback = button5Clicked
  button6.callback = button6Clicked
  button7.callback = button7Clicked
  view1 = View()
  view1.add_item(button1)
  view1.add_item(button2)
  view1.add_item(button3)
  view1.add_item(button4)
  view1.add_item(button5)
  view1.add_item(button6)
  view1.add_item(button7)

  await ctx.send(piece + " turn\n" + L1 + "\n" + L2 + "\n" + L3 + "\n" + L4 + "\n" + L5 + "\n" +
                 L6,
                 view=view1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in the docs: [I did it for you](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.edit)
The docs is the most useful thing readily available to you.

```
.
.
message = piece + " turn\n" +L1 + "\n" + L2 + "\n" + L3 + "\n" + L4 + "\n" + L5 + "\n" + L6
m = await ctx.send(message, view=view1) #btw this still sends the message
.
.
m.edit(content=message, view=...)
```